# how to put an arraylist in order with unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i use a code to put an arraylist on unity and i don't understand why that's don't work and i'm getting no error, i hope someone can help me.
i explain : my code is suppose to send a name of a company. They are all repertoried in "tabChampsInfos[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYsUu.png)". And with the "for" all name of company will be contened in " txtNompComp.text". And that's work but not in order and i dont uderstand why. I use Unity that's why i need to use "Length-2". I don't have error.

[that is two "AffichCompClone"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYsUu.png)

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        tabLigneInfos = datacr.RecupTxt(urlArrivee);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabLigneInfos.Length-2 ;i++)
        {
            tabChampsInfos = tabLigneInfos[i].Split(',');

            txtNompComp.text = tabChampsInfos[1];
            string url = tabChampsInfos[2];

            WWW www = new WWW(url);
            yield return www;

            GameObject AffichCompClone = Instantiate(AffichCompReg, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, parent.transform);
            toDestroyList.Add(AffichCompClone);

            alternanceCouleur();
            GameObject infosClone = Instantiate(infos, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity,position.transform);
            infosClone.name = "infos0" + i;
            infosNomLien.Add(infosClone.name, tabChampsInfos[2]);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        tabLigneInfos = datacr.RecupTxt(urlArrivee);
        Array.Sort(tabLigneInfos);   

        for (int i = 0; i < tabLigneInfos.Length-2 ;i++)
        {

            tabChampsInfos = tabLigneInfos[i].Split(',');


            txtNompComp.text = tabChampsInfos[1];
            string url = tabChampsInfos[2];

            WWW www = new WWW(url);
            yield return www;


            GameObject AffichCompClone = Instantiate(AffichCompReg, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, parent.transform);
            toDestroyList.Add(AffichCompClone);

            alternanceCouleur();
            GameObject infosClone = Instantiate(infos, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity,position.transform);
            infosClone.name = "infos0" + i;
            infosNomLien.Add(infosClone.name, tabChampsInfos[2]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's still don't work and i  knwo why tabChampsInfos have nothing before the "for" i will keep working on it. thanks to help me and if you are an more advice to help me , tell what do you don't understand or what do you need.
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

In c# we normally just use the generic List class... In fact, until today, I had no idea C# had an ArrayList.

Either way, ArrayList does have a Sort function, so what you're looking for is `tabLigneInfos.Sort()`. If you need a more advanced method of sorting, I would also consider looking into LINQ.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `ArrayList` is from a long long time ago (.Net 1.0, the first version of .Net and C#). The language was young, missing many of the current features. Notably, generics were not part of the language, so there was the ArrayList class, which you can consider as a `List<object>` With the coming of generics (.Net 2.0, ~2005 if I'm not wrong), there is actually no reason to use ArrayList instead of a typed List<something>